# Which notification triggers textViewDidChange?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsnotifications

I believe the notification

```
UITextView.textDidChangeNotification
```

is what triggers

```
textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView)
```

to run.

However it does ***not*** trigger

```
 textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
```

to run.

In fact which is "the" notification which triggers `textViewDidChange` to run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure firsthand how to answer your question, but the documentation states the following:

> The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes to the text. This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes.
>
> Implementation of this method is optional.

From here:
[Text View Did Change Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange?language=objc)

Comment: Hi Alan, I really understand that, thanks.  As it says in the question, the actual internal mechanism which makes textViewDidChangeSelection run, is, the notification "UITextView.textDidChangeNotification".  That notification does NOT make "textViewDidChange" run.  The question is which notification is it that makes "textViewDidChange" run.

Comment: Note, Alan, you would use this in issues such as subclassing UITextView, etc.